# Sort order in postgresql for japanese words in hiragana

Tags: postgresql, sorting, unicode

I have a version 9.6.2 postgresql database with encoding UTF8 and collation en_GB.UTF8. One of my tables has a field containing Japanese Hiragana characters only. The problem is that sorting this field in the normal way through SQL (... ORDER BY [field name] ...) does not produce the expected (by me at least) results. Instead, the ordering is as if the rows are sorted by first by length (of the field contents) and only then by the characters. So for example, instead of getting:

あめ うえ おとこ かわり き し ひ

as I would expect, the order comes out as:

き し ひ あめ うえ おとこ かわり

What am I missing?

Comment: `t=# with a as (select string_to_array('あめ うえ おとこ かわり き し ひ',' ') a) select unnest(a) from a order by 1;` shows me your expected result on mac...

Comment: thanks for that - on both my mac (postgres 9.6.2) and my centos 7 (postgres 9.2.18) your expression results in the unexpected order (the one where the word length seems to count more than the actual characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting collation `C` explicitly?

```
t=# with a as (select string_to_array('あめ うえ おとこ かわり き し ひ' COLLATE "en_GB.UTF-8",' ') a) select unnest(a) from a order by 1;
 unnest
--------
 き
 し
 ひ
 あめ
 うえ
 おとこ
 かわり
(7 rows)

t=# with a as (select string_to_array('あめ うえ おとこ かわり き し ひ' COLLATE "C",' ') a) select unnest(a) from a order by 1;
 unnest
--------
 あめ
 うえ
 おとこ
 かわり
 き
 し
 ひ
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Oh - that certainly works and surely must be a big clue as to what is going on. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: please accept and/or upvote my answer then - I'm trying to build a good reputation.

Comment: It's worth noting that the following now works as expected (the table name is 'vocabs' and the field name is 'kana'): SELECT kana FROM vocabs ORDER BY kana COLLATE "C";

Comment: And also, since I'm working in the context of Ruby on Rails, with the model name 'Vocab', the following also works as expected: Vocab.order('kana COLLATE "C"')